# Auditing specific syscall parameter value

Tags: linux, system-calls, auditing, timestamp

I want to deploy auditing focused on some more sophisticated scenarious on my GNU/Linux boxes, for instance execution of commands like touch -m 'faketime' somefile. I straced the exec and found out the difference between normal touch and touch with timestamp modifying flag.
These are respectively:

> utimes("/proc/self/fd/0", NULL)         = 0
>
> utimes("/proc/self/fd/0", {{1364383142, 0}, {1364383160, 875693}}) = 0

So it seems to be easy to catch suspicius occurances of the utimes syscall; its second (a1) argument has to be NULL. I tried to set the following audit rule:

> -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S utimes -F a1!=0 -k TIMESTAMP_TAMPERING

However it doesn't catch the call. Text representation of the value (NULL) is not accepted by auditd in a1-4 arguments, at least I got trouble trying to achieve it.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm also interested in auditing syscalls. I want to get the arguments sent in the call. I'm trying to do API Hooking via the auditd frameworkd, just researching methods that are not the standard LD_PRELOAD